# phpDesigner 8 - Show elements tree

Tags: php, html, editor, phpdesigner

Since i installed phpDesigner i am trying to find how to set up to show element tree. 
I know that many people will suggest to change editor but i tried all of them for last 2 weeks. I am moving from notepad++ only due syntax check.

Good thing with phpDesigner what is better then NetBeans and phpStorm is that there is code highlighting, it's lighter, and the most important **FTP remote** without bugs. Program itself have some bugs but for now i really cant live without element tree and i am sure that many people need that.

[image: Element Tree witch have every editor except phpDesigner]  [image: Element Tree witch have every editor except phpDesigner]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean the Structure View:

[image: Tool Windows]

Comment: I believe this is phpStorm, not phpDesigner

Comment: sry, I misread this - never used phpDesigner - have you tried both?